# Error when installing JServer JVM in Oracle XE on Linux AMI

Tags: oracle, installation, java, oracle-xe

I'm trying to install OJVM on Oracle 11g (11.2.0.2.0) on Amazon Linux AMI (20016.09).  And I'm getting the following error after running *initjvm.sql*:

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> create or replace java system
> begin if initjvmaux.startstep('CREATE_JAVA_SYSTEM') then
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-29538: Java not installed
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.INITJVMAUX", line 23
> ORA-06512: at line 5

Running

```
SQL> select comp_name, version, status from dba_registry;
```

shows this:

```
COMP_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION                        STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------
Oracle Application Express
4.0.2.00.09                    VALID

Oracle XML Database
11.2.0.2.0                     VALID

Oracle Text
11.2.0.2.0                     VALID


COMP_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION                        STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------
Oracle Database Catalog Views
11.2.0.2.0                     VALID

Oracle Database Packages and Types
11.2.0.2.0                     VALID

JServer JAVA Virtual Machine
                               LOADING


COMP_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERSION                        STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------------------
Oracle XDK
11.2.0.2.0                     VALID
```

The install is started and up until that point shows no errors, and everything seems to run and complete successfully, and the *dba_registry* shows an in progress install.  Anyone have any ideas on what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

A basic overview of feature availability for different database editions:

[Products and Services - Database - Enterprise Edition - Comparisons](https://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/enterprise-edition/comparisons/index.html)

Java is not available in Express Edition.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the OJVM can be loaded.  I've done done with XE - Oracle 11g  on Windows 7.   I'm wonderijng why the same load would not be possible for XE on Linux.